# Transforming HOC with context into react pure function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a HOC which functionality will be really simple. Add to the wrapped component a prop from the context.

I have been able to do that this way:

```
const WithForm = WrappedComponent => class extends Component {
  static contextTypes = {
    ctx: PropTypes.object
  };
  render() {
    return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} ctx={this.context.ctx} />;
  }
};

export default WithForm;
```

Now I would like this to be a pure function, since I just have the render() method.

So, looking at [Official guide](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html#referencing-context-in-stateless-functional-components), I did the following:

```
const WithForm = WrappedComponent => (props, context) => {
  console.log('props', props, 'context', context);
  return <WrappedComponent {...props} ctx={context.ctx} />;
};

WithForm.contextTypes = {
  ctx: PropTypes.object
};

export default WithForm;
```

However, **context** is coming empty: {}

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
const withForm = WrappedComponent => {
    let WithForm = (props, context) => {
      console.log('props', props, 'context', context);
      return <WrappedComponent {...props} ctx={context.ctx} />;
    };

    WithForm.contextTypes = {
      ctx: PropTypes.object
    };
    return WithForm;
}

export default withForm;
```

It's because you are trying to set context on the wrapping function and not on the pure function.

In the original `class` code snippet you set it on the inner function correctly.

Comment: That totally worked! Thanks for your explanation about what was exactly happening